# Parsing python json response in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am parsing json response in jquery.

`console.log(response)` gives

```
{"result": [{"surprise": "24.79%"}, {"joy": "18.73%"}, {"anticipation": "14.61%"}, {"disgust": "10.54%"}, {"sadness": "8.75%"}, {"trust": "8.32%"}, {"anger": "8.12%"}, {"fear": "6.14%"}]}
```

I trying to parse this json into variable like this:

```
val res = JSON.parse(response);
document.getElementById("anger").innerHTML = res['result'][6]['anger'];
document.getElementById("disgust").innerHTML = res['result'][3]['disgust'];
document.getElementById("fear").innerHTML = res['result'][7]['fear'];
document.getElementById("joy").innerHTML = res['result'][1]['joy'];
document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = res['result'][4]['sadness'];
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML = res['result'][0]['surprise'];
document.getElementById("trust").innerHTML = res['result'][5]['trust'];
document.getElementById("anticipation").innerHTML = res['result'][2]['anticipation'];
```

which gives

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

at `val res = JSON.parse(response);`

What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Please post a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Feedlynews can provide your code where did you fetch this data ?

Comment: JSON.parse is not part of jQuery

Comment: Anyways, maybe it's already JSON you are getting back and can just do `response.result[0].anger`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `val` to `var`:

```js
var response = '{"result": [{"surprise": "24.79%"}, {"joy": "18.73%"}, {"anticipation": "14.61%"}, {"disgust": "10.54%"}, {"sadness": "8.75%"}, {"trust": "8.32%"}, {"anger": "8.12%"}, {"fear": "6.14%"}]}';


var res = JSON.parse(response);
document.getElementById("anger").innerHTML = res['result'][6]['anger'];
document.getElementById("disgust").innerHTML = res['result'][3]['disgust'];
document.getElementById("fear").innerHTML = res['result'][7]['fear'];
document.getElementById("joy").innerHTML = res['result'][1]['joy'];
document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = res['result'][4]['sadness'];
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML = res['result'][0]['surprise'];
document.getElementById("trust").innerHTML = res['result'][5]['trust'];
document.getElementById("anticipation").innerHTML = res['result'][2]['anticipation'];
```

```html
<div id="anger"></div>
<div id="disgust"></div>
<div id="fear"></div>
<div id="joy"></div>
<div id="sadness"></div>
<div id="surprise"></div>
<div id="trust"></div>
<div id="anticipation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change "val" to "var".  Then here's how I'd do this:

```
res.result.forEach( function(elem){
    for (var e in elem){
        $('.' + e).html(elem[e]);
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/pc2q917f/